# Consume GIT rest API with TFS

Tags: c#, git, rest, tfs

I want to make a tool where I can see all the pull request data. We have multiple repositories so it is very difficult to find new pull request. I want a place where I can see all the pull request.(We are using TFS server) I will create a Angular project for it. I just want to know how I will be able to consume GIT rest APIs.

Any suggestion.

Comment: So are you using git or TFS?

Comment: We are using git repository on TFS

Comment: @aquaballin Those two terms aren't mutually exclusive. TFS is a platform, which supports two types of version control: Git and TFVC.

Comment: @DanielMann you are right. We are using TFS platform with GIT version control

Comment: wow I had no idea that there was git integration with TFS, learn something new everyday

Comment: Did you had a look to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=vsts-rest-4.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TFS Rest API to get the Pull Requests from TFS.

Retrieve all pull requests matching a specified criteria:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?api-version=4.1
```

With optional parameters:

```
GET https://{accountName}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullrequests?searchCriteria.includeLinks={searchCriteria.includeLinks}&searchCriteria.sourceRefName={searchCriteria.sourceRefName}&searchCriteria.sourceRepositoryId={searchCriteria.sourceRepositoryId}&searchCriteria.targetRefName={searchCriteria.targetRefName}&searchCriteria.status={searchCriteria.status}&searchCriteria.reviewerId={searchCriteria.reviewerId}&searchCriteria.creatorId={searchCriteria.creatorId}&searchCriteria.repositoryId={searchCriteria.repositoryId}&maxCommentLength={maxCommentLength}&$skip={$skip}&$top={$top}&api-version=4.1
```

For example, Just completed pull requests:

```
GET https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/_apis/git/repositories/3411ebc1-d5aa-464f-9615-0b527bc66719/pullrequests?searchCriteria.status=completed&api-version=4.1
```

Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/pull%20requests?view=vsts-rest-4.1) about the Rest API for PR, and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/git/?view=vsts-rest-4.1) about the Rest API for all GIT options.